# requesting ajax via HttpWebRequest

Tags: ajax, encoding, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm writing a simple application that will download some piece of data from a website then I can use it later for any purpose.

The following is the request and response copied from Firebug as the browser did that.
When you type `http://x5.travian.com.sa/ajax.php?f=k7&x=18&y=-186&xx=12&yy=-192`
you will get a PHP file has some data.
But when I make a request with `HttpWebRequest` I get wrong data (some unknown letters)

Can anyone help me in that? Do I have to make some encodings or what?

**Response**

```
 1. Server  nginx
 2. Date    Tue, 04 Jan 2011 23:03:49 GMT
 3. Content-Type    application/json; charset=UTF-8
 4. Transfer-Encoding   chunked
 5. Connection  keep-alive
 6. X-Powered-By    PHP/5.2.8
 7. Expires Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
 8. Last-Modified   Tue, 04 Jan 2011 23:03:49 GMT
 9. Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
 10. Pragma no-cache
 11. Content-Encoding   gzip
 12. Vary   Accept-Encoding
```

**Request**

```
 1. Host    x5.travian.com.sa
 2. User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) 
 3. Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13
 4. Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
 5. Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
 6. Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
 7. Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
 8. Keep-Alive  115
 9. Connection  keep-alive
 10. Cookie CAD=57878984%231292375897%230%230%23%230; T3E=%3DImYykTN2EzMmhjO5QTM2QDN2oDM1ITOyoDOxIjM4EDN5ITM6gjO4MDOxIWZyQWMipTZu9metl2ctl2c6MDNxADN6MDNxADNjMDNxADNjMDNxADN; orderby_b1=0; orderby_b=0; orderby2=0; orderby=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I used wget on unix to hit the site, and I got back a page that had arabic characters in it. As per the response headers the page is encoded as UTF8.

If you can show the code you are using, we could provide feedback. Maybe there is a bug in your code in the way you are interpreting the response stream.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it is solved, the response was encoded with the gzib encode, so I just decode it with the gzibdecodestream...